# Angular running custom plugin after build

Tags: angular, webpack, html-webpack-plugin, angular-builder, ngx-build-plus

I am trying to add `async-css-plugin` (https://www.npmjs.com/package/async-css-plugin) to Angular project. What this plugin does is, it converts the external style link tag in html file to something like:

```
<link href=app.cfadf482.css rel=stylesheet media=print onload="this.media='all'">
```

I know we can extend webpack config, for this I am using `ngx-build-plus` (https://github.com/manfredsteyer/ngx-build-plus)

And I have added below config `extend.webpack.config` file:

```
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
const AsyncCssPlugin = require("async-css-plugin");

module.exports = {
  plugins: [
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin(),
    new AsyncCssPlugin({ /* options */ })
  ]
};
```

But now when I run `npm run build -- --prod --extra-webpack-config extend.webpack.config.js`, it doesn't work.

it doesn't modify the index.html file.

Can anyone please guide if I'm missing something?

Thank you!

**Update**
Here's the reproduction repo https://github.com/andreashuber69/async-css-angular-example

And here's the plugin source code https://github.com/andreashuber69/async-css-plugin/blob/37e9030fc4791370cd7efaf25a7275ff425c2d36/src/AsyncCssPlugin.ts

Comment: Change it to "customWebpackConfig": { "path": "./custom-webpack.config.js", "mergeStrategies": { "module.rules": "prepend" }, "replaceDuplicatePlugins": true }

Comment: tried @naveen ?

Comment: Yes still no success, the stylesheet tag isn't updated. :(

Comment: the prepend one should work and prepend makes sure that your script runs in last. refer this :- https://www.npmjs.com/package/@angular-builders/custom-webpack

Comment: try removing --extra-webpack-config flag from your build command and keep the config as i gave in above comment?

Comment: Didn't work either

Comment: "customWebpackConfig": { "path": "./custom-webpack.config.js", "mergeStrategies": { "module.rules": "prepend" }} try this config and remove --extra-webpack-config from your command?

Comment: Tried, didn't work

Comment: can you give access to your code as github repo?

Comment: You can use same repo https://github.com/aakashgarg19/async-css just update the angular.json file and set `"outputPath": "dist"`

Comment: ok, let me check by changing outputPath

Comment: got your point fixing it and commiting in same repo so that you can see changes, will let you know once changes are done.

Comment: is it mandatory to use ngx-build-plus?

Comment: Angular CLI builder, `@angular-devkit/build-angular`, doesn't have an `extraWebpackConfig` so we need a third party builder like `ngx-build-plus` for custom webpack config.

Comment: Hey dude just a thought, you were having correct index.html if output path was dist/async right? For now have a post build command to copy that index.html from there to dist? because its not happening from webpack config?

Comment: The file with changes from plugin is half finished and not final file.

Comment: Can't help then, as plugin is running before Angular's webpack final output. And i don't know what's written in cli's webpack. I tried various options.

Comment: No worries, thanks anyways for your time.

Answer (score 0):

Updated Webpack Config :-

```
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin')
const AsyncCssPlugin = require("async-css-plugin");
var path = require('path');
module.exports = {
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, './dist')
  },
  plugins: [
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin(),
    new AsyncCssPlugin({ logLevel: "info" })
  ]
};
```

**Change Angular.json Customwebpackconfig like :-**

```
"customWebpackConfig": { "path": "./custom-webpack.config.js", "mergeStrategies": { "module.rules": "prepend" }, "replaceDuplicatePlugins": true }
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/214565/discussion-on-answer-by-aakash-garg-angular-running-custom-plugin-after-build).